# ImportError at / cannot import name patterns with different Django Version

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am running to a weird error. I have only a single installed django version 1.7.11 and when I tested my website to see it is working I ended up having the error:

```
ImportError at /  cannot import name patterns.
```

I am using 1.7.11 and patterns is supported of that version of Django but here is the weird thing, when I checked the django version on the site where it complained with the error it says:

```
Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

However, when I enter the python shell:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)  
>>> import django; django.VERSION
(1, 7, 11, 'final', 0)
```

and I only have a one version of Django installed. Why is this happening?
I am using https://www.pythonanywhere.com to run the django app.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance